# Setting Lasso 9 permissions

Tags: macos, permissions, acl, lasso-lang

I'm attempting to configure a OSX Mavericks server running Apache and Lasso. For security and convenience I only want users belonging to a specific "web" group to be able to access the web root. I have succeeded in letting both permitted regular users and Apache (_www) access the files, but I cannot for my life manage to set the correct permissions for Lasso. I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

Basically, what I have done is the following:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o create web
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a _www -t user web
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a _lasso -t user web
sudo chgrp -R web webroot
sudo chmod -R 770 webroot
```

This apparently works for Apache, but any lasso files merely output a Lasso permission error:

```
An unhandled failure during a web request
Error Code: 13
Error Msg: Permission denied - While opening //Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/...
```

I have also tried adding the _www and _lasso groups to the web group, as well as creating a new Lasso instance in the instance manager with the effective group set to "web".

Strangely, setting permissions to the _lasso user or group directly on the files (i.e. not through the web group) seems to work which makes me believe there's something wrong with how I'm creating my  ACLs.

A little more info:

```
ls -l@e example.lasso
-rwxrwx---+ 1 danielpervan  web  0 Feb 19 15:20 example.lasso
 0: user:_spotlight inherited allow read,execute
```

Comment: First, the permissions error you say you're getting when accessing Lasso files, what is that? Is it a Lasso error and error stack or an Apache error? Second, I would either add the web user to the _lasso group or the _lasso user to the web group. Third, if you could post the result of an "ls -l@e /path/to/lassofile.lasso" as an example, it may help.

Comment: @bfad It's certainly a lasso error. I edited my question to include the said error.

Comment: Upon further inspection with ls -l@e it seems like I never really applied the ACL to my files and merely set the POSIX group. Though, since I'm not really that familiar with how OSX handles ACLs together with the POSIX permissions, I'm not sure why this worked with Apache and not Lasso. Actually adding the ACLs to the file seems to fix the problem, but I'm gonna play around with this a bit more and see that works all the way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered problems similar to this when I have ACLs above and beyond the standard Unix permissions. From your post, it looks like there are some ACLs on the example.lasso file. I would run the following script on your web root to remove *all* ACLs from every folder / file:

```
sudo chmod -R -N /path/to/webroot/
```

If that doesn't work, verify that the _lasso user is part of the web group:

```
dscl . -read /groups/web | grep GroupMembership
```